# How to make simple_form do what I want with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

Each `survey` `has_many` `results`, and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` `results`.

**/app/models/survey.rb:**

```
attr_accessible :results_attributes
has_many :results
accepts_nested_attributes_for :results
```

Each result is either selected or not selected:

**/db/schema.rb:**

```
create_table "results", :force => true do |t|
  t.boolean  "selected", :default => false
  t.integer "survey_id"
end
```

Sometimes `@survey.additive == true`. In those cases, any number of results can be selected. You'd represent this with a series of checkboxes, one for each `result` in `@survey.results`.

Sometimes `@survey.additive == false`. In those cases, only one result can be selected. You'd represent this with a series of radio buttons, one for each `result` in `@survey.results`.

I am using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and HAML.

I'm trying to write `/app/views/surveys/_form.html.haml` so that it will create a series of radio buttons to choose which results are selected when `@survey.additive == false`.

(From there it should be easy to extrapolate the code to also create a series of checkboxes when `@survey.additive == true`.)

My first attempt was:

```
= simple_form_for [@competitor, @survey] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.simple_fields_for :results do |r|
    = r.input :selected, :as => :radio_buttons, :label => r.name
  = f.button :submit, :id => 'submit_survey'
```

That earned me an `undefined method 'name' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007fbd1f687048>` error.

My second move was removing `:label => r.name`, but the result was four separate rows of radio buttons, each row labelled "Selected" and each containing a "Yes" radio button and a "No" radio button. By separate I mean that selecting Yes in one row deselected No in that row but had no affect on the radio buttons in the other rows. (What I actually needed was four connected radio buttons, each labelled after with a `result.name` in `@survey.results`, so that deselecting any of the four would deselect the other three.)

After that, I tried many variations, but so far all my attempts have failed. What should I do?

Comment: I don't see an integer attribute called `survey_id` (or `t.references :survey`, whichever you prefer) in your `results` migration. I assume you filtered that out for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: Indeed. It contains `t.integer "survey_id"`. Just updated question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `underfined method 'name'` error can be overcome by using `r.object.name`.

If you can have many results with `selected` set to true, this will suffice and it should work in the situation described above. If not, please read on.

The thing with radio_buttons on a boolean is that they will generate a `yes` and `no` option. If you only want one selected result, I suggest switching to a situation where Survey `has_many :results` and `belongs_to :selected_result`. Then you'll be able to build a set of radio buttons for setting the `selected_result_id`, generated from `survey.results`.

If that's not an option, you will have to validate Survey with a custom validation so that it can only have one selected_result (add a scope for that) and build a set of radio buttons generated from `survey.results` for an `attr_accessor :selected_result_id`. Then, in your controller, you will have to iterate through the results and set `result.selected = false` on every result except the selected one.

Comment: The `r.object.name` trick worked, thanks. I'm thinking about using either the postgres_ext gem or Rails 4 to add `t.integer :selections, :array => true` to `@survey`. This would store the IDs of each selected `result` in `@survey.results`. Potentially, I'd then ditch the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` relationship altogether. What do you think?

Comment: If that's an option for you: have you looked at serialization? I haven't used in since Rails 2, but you could consider adding a text attribute `result_ids` and calling `serialize :result_ids` in your model, so you can store a simple Array or Hash in it, enabling you to write a `results` method where you return `Result.where("id IN '?'", result_ids)`. And you can even expand that to a more elaborate variable in which you also set the selected results. Something like `{:ids => [1,2,3], :selected => [2]}`. However, I think my suggestion (3rd paragraph) might be easier to maintain.